# Two divs not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get Heading 5 and 6 to align next to each other much like how I have 3 and 4 aligned. However, for some reason 6 doesn't want to move over to the right. My guess is that there is some sort of style I created prior that is stopping it. I've tried creating new div[enter image description here][1]s, moving etc around.

Comment: Put some code in your post. HTML and CSS.

Comment: You need to use better title and add some more description to your question. By the looks of it, this seem simple to solve, try googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix: Add this to your CSS;

```
#movie {
    min-width: 345px;
}
```

The real fix: Rewrite your entire CSS/HTML

Comment: Thanks for that, and yea I was going to rewrite it. It's really messy and redundant.